# Retrieve related invoice of an applied payment in NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a requirement; where I need to load a list of payments that were updated between a specified date/time range. And for each invoice; I need to get a list of `internal` id (aka invoice id) that payment has been applied to (since a payment can be *applied to* one or more invoices).

I tried to achieve this using a search query like this:

```
var paymentSearch = search.create({           
    type: search.Type.CUSTOMER_PAYMENT,
    filters: [
        ['lastmodifieddate', 'within', from_datetime, to_datetime],
         'and',
        ['appliedToTransaction.tranid', search.Operator.ISNOTEMPTY, '@NONE']
    ],
    columns: [
            'entity',
            'tranid',
        search.createColumn({
            name: 'internalid',
            join: 'appliedToTransaction'
        })
    ]
});

for (var i = 0; i < paymentsPagedData.pageRanges.length; i++) {
    var currentPage = paymentsPagedData.fetch(i);
    currentPage.data.forEach(function(result) {

        // TEST
        var appliedToInvoiceIds = result.getValue({ name: 'internalid', join: 'appliedToTransaction' });

    }
}
```

When I inspected the `appliedToInvoiceIds`, it only appears to be returning a single value, the first invoice this payment has been applied to. How can I get all of the invoice ids that the payment has been applied to?

I tried inspecting the `result` object (inside the `forEach` loop) to see what was inside and this is what I saw:

```
{
    "recordType": "customerpayment",
    "id": "25911",
    "values": {
        "entity": [
            {
                "value": "761",
                "text": "COMPANY NAME INC"
            }
        ],
        "tranid": "722",
        "appliedToTransaction.internalid": [
            {
                "value": "2676",
                "text": "2676"
            },
            {
                "value": "2658",
                "text": "2658"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see on the result object of the payment; it has `appliedToTransaction.internalid` which is an array and has two items in it. How can I retrieve these?

Is there an alternate version of `result.getValue(...)` available for retrieving array of items/field values via a join?

Answer (score 2):

You need to return true at the end of your forEach. Otherwise it will only return one result.